# What does the "." action property in form tag do?

Tags: html, forms, action

I have a form tag that has `action="."`. What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never saw it in a `action` but it means "same directory" just like ".." means previous directory.

If the filename is omitted on the action (`action=""`) the form simply redirect on the same file, using the `.` otherwise the form redirect on the same directory without file name...

File http://localhost/index.html

```
<form action="">  // redirect on http://localhost/index.html?
<form action="."> // redirect on http://localhost/?
```

Answer (score 2):

The same as any other action attribute — it specifies the URI to submit to.

`.` is a relative URI equivalent to `./`, i.e. the same as the current URI with the fragment identifier, query string and everything after the last `/` stripped off.

For example, from `http://example.com/foo/bar.html?baz=1#fragment` it resolves to `http://example.com/foo/`.